# iTextpdf PdfPTable how to add cell in the any position in the grid?

Tags: java, pdf, cell, xls

I'm trying to convert old XLS table generator to PDF table generator. And in HSSFWOrkbook actually possible set cell index on creation. But how I can do the same for PdfPTable in PDF?
Only method avaliable .addCell(). Not too much.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using PdfCell array:

```
ncols = 6; // number of columns
nrows = 8; // number of rows
Pdfcell[][] cells = new PdfCell[nrows][ncols];

// To create the table cells
for(int icol=0; icol<ncols; icol++) {
    for(int irow=0; irow<nrows; irow++) {
        cells[irow][icol] = new PdfCell(new Phrase(
                "Col:" + icol + ", Row:" + irow));
    }
}

// To add the cells to table
for(int irow=0; irow<nrows; irow++) {
    for(int icol=0; icol<ncols; icol++) {
        table.addCell(cells[irow][icol]);
    }
}
```